# Stored procedure (works fine): Internal server error

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli, phpmyadmin, internal-server-error

I'm using this stored procedure: http://pastebin.com/Jn8F6SD7

This runs fine in the following cases:

1. mysql console
2. PHPMyAdmin "execute" button: https://gyazo.com/7b27d5ce5bae6f8dfa143b159daa9248

The same Stored Procedure gives errors in the following cases:

1. PHPMyAdmin SQL-tab: https://gyazo.com/91e2e88e27d0e24911bcae47f608681a (Internal server error)
2. PHP mysqli functions (The DirectAdmin logs show: out of memory, the php error is: packets out of order)

I'm using PHP 7.0 and MySQL 5.6

Comment: How many records is the procedure returning?

Comment: Depends on the input, but at this moment around 8.